# Is there a way to display text without setting cursor position

Tags: c#

So basically, I wanted to know if there were a way to display text without setting a cursor position

Like, if I wanted to display '0' at point 5, 7

I know I can do

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(5,7);
Console.Write("0");
```

But I need my cursor for something else in my program. Is there a way I can display 0 at that point without setting the position?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: have you read the documentation on the following C# MSDN Method for `Console.SetCursorPostions` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Try to capture prev position and then set again:

```
Console.WriteLine("abc");

var prevX = Console.CursorLeft;
var prevY = Console.CursorTop;

Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 17);
Console.Write("0");

Console.SetCursorPosition(prevX, prevY);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the cursor position for `Console.Write` to know where to actually write. So you can't avoid using `SetCursorPosition`. However, you can get the current position with `CursorLeft` and `CursorTop` and then restore them afterwards (as in Giorgi's answer).

You could wrap this all up in a handy method like this:

```
public static void WriteAt(string s, int x, int y)
{
    // save the current position
    var origCol = Console.CursorLeft;
    var origRow = Console.CursorTop;
    // move to where you want to write
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
    Console.Write(s);
    // restore the previous position
    Console.SetCursorPosition(origCol, origRow);
}
```

Which you'd use like this:

```
WriteAt("foo",5,15);
```

You could even use an extension method like this (unfortunately you can't add an extension to `Console` because it's a static class, but you can add it to `String` instead!):

```
public static class StringConsoleHelper
{
    public static void WriteAt(this string s, int x, int y)
    {
        // save the current position
        var origCol = Console.CursorLeft;
        var origRow = Console.CursorTop;
        // move to where you want to write
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write(s);
        // restore the previous position
        Console.SetCursorPosition(origCol, origRow);
    }
}
```

So now you'd be able to do something like:

```
"foo".WriteAt(5,15);
```